# Taylor's Theorem for a function whose domain is $\mathbb R^n$

Tags: real-analysis, taylor-expansion

In my text book,

Taylor theorem:

> Let $f:A\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$   be of class $C^{r}$   for
>   $A\subset\mathbb{R}^{n}$   an open set. Let $x,y\in A$  , and suppose
>   that the segment joining $x$   and $y$   lies in $A$  . Then there is
>   a point $c$   on that segment such that
>
> $f(y)-f(x)=\sum_{k=1}^{r-1}\frac{1}{k!}D^{k}f(x)(y-x,...,y-x)+\frac{1}{r!}D^{r}f(c)(y-x,...,y-x)$
>
> where $D^{k}f(x)(y-x,...,y-x)$   denote $D^{k}f(x)$   as a $k$ 
>   -linear map appiled to the k  -tuple $(y-x,...,y-x)$  .

Then if $f(x_{0}+h)-f(x_{0})=\frac{1}{2}D^{2}f(c)(h,h)$ and $f$ has a local minimum at $x_0$, then can I say that **"for all $h\in\mathbb R$",**  $H _{x_0}(f)(h,h)\geq 0$, that is, the Hessian matrix $H$ is positive semidefinite by convexity and openess of $\mathbb R^n$?